# Plot continuous field lines of bar magnet B field using StreamPlot

Tags: plotting, physics

I want to plot the field lines of the B field of a bar magnet. The problem is that they have a very sharp bend when entering the magnet and Mathematica stops tracing the field lines.

Here is how I tried to do it:

[(Notebook in Wolfram Cloud)](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/3b5ce60e-1588-4af1-9677-2bd816172853)

```
ψBarMagnetHeld  = WolframAlpha["magnetic potential rectangular bar magnet",{{"Result",1},"Input"}];
ψBarMagnet[{x_, y_, z_}, {a_, b_, c_}]=(ReleaseHold[ψBarMagnetHeld]/. {QuantityVariable[x_,y_]:>x})/Subscript[M, 0];
ℋBarMagnet[{x_, y_, z_}, {a_, b_, c_}]=-D[ψBarMagnet[{x, y, z}, {a, b, c}], {{x, y, z}}];
ℬBarMagnet[{x_, y_, z_}, {a_, b_, c_}]=ℋBarMagnet[{x,y,z},{a,b,c}] + {0,0,1}UnitStep[(a/2)^2-x^2]UnitStep[(b/2)^2-y^2]UnitStep[(c/2)^2-z^2];

crossSectionFieldPlot[field_, fieldStrength_] := 
 Block[{a = 1.5, b = 0.5, c = 5.5},
    StreamPlot[fieldStrength ,   {x, -a, a}, {z, -c, c}, 
    PlotRange -> {{-2 c, 2 c}, {-2 c, 2 c}}, 
    PlotRangeClipping -> True, VectorScale -> Medium, 
    StreamPoints -> {{0, 0}, {9, 0}, {6, 0}}, AspectRatio -> 1, Frame -> None]
 ]

crossSectionFieldPlot["ℬ",ℬBarMagnet[{x,0,z},{a,b,c}][[{1,3}]]]
```

The image below shows two field lines that work and one that is not tracked.

[image: image shows two field lines that work and one that is not tracked]

Comment: Please post the Mathematica code.

Comment: The graph generated in v14.0 differs from the one in your Notebook in Wolfram Cloud.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `Scaled[1]` in the third argument of `StreamPoints` to draw *at least* one complete stream of each stream point:

```
StreamPoints -> {{{0, 0}, {6, 0}, {9, 0}}, Automatic, Scaled[1]}
```

[image]

Comment: The graph obtained in v14.0 is incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

To show continues field line we use option `StreamScale -> None`

```
\[Psi]BarMagnetHeld  = 
  WolframAlpha[
   "magnetic potential rectangular bar magnet", {{"Result", 1}, 
    "Input"}];
\[Psi]BarMagnet[{x_, y_, z_}, {a_, b_, 
    c_}] = (ReleaseHold[\[Psi]BarMagnetHeld] /. {QuantityVariable[x_, 
        y_] :> x})/Subscript[M, 0];
\[ScriptCapitalH]BarMagnet[{x_, y_, z_}, {a_, b_, 
    c_}] = -D[\[Psi]BarMagnet[{x, y, z}, {a, b, c}], {{x, y, z}}];
\[ScriptCapitalB]BarMagnet[{x_, y_, z_}, {a_, b_, 
    c_}] = \[ScriptCapitalH]BarMagnet[{x, y, z}, {a, b, c}] + {0, 0, 
     1} UnitStep[(a/2)^2 - x^2] UnitStep[(b/2)^2 - 
      y^2] UnitStep[(c/2)^2 - z^2];

crossSectionFieldPlot[field_, fieldStrength_] := 
 Block[{a = 1.5, b = 0.5, c = 5.5},
    StreamPlot[fieldStrength ,   {x, -c, c}, {z, -c, c}, 
                               PlotRange -> All,
                                 StreamPoints -> Fine, 
   AspectRatio -> Automatic, Frame -> None, 
   StreamColorFunction -> "Rainbow", StreamScale -> None, 
   VectorPoints -> Fine, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
   MaxRecursion -> 10]
  ]
bar2 = With[{a = 1.5,  c = 5.5}, 
  Graphics[{Opacity[.25], Rectangle[{-a, -c}/2, {a, c}/2]}, 
   Axes -> False, Frame -> False]];
Show[crossSectionFieldPlot[
  "\[ScriptCapitalB]", \[ScriptCapitalB]BarMagnet[{x, 0, z}, {a, b, 
     c}] [[{1, 3}]]] , bar2]
```

[image: Figure 1]

To solve the problem of broken lines we can use hand made code. First, we define interpolation functions for $B_x,B_z$ to exclude singularities as follows

```
Bx = Interpolation[
  Flatten[Table[{x, 
     z, \[ScriptCapitalB]BarMagnet[{x, 0., z}, {1.5, .5, 
        5.5}] [[1]]}, {x, 0, 10, .1}, {z, 0, 10, .1}], 1]];

Bz = Interpolation[
  Flatten[Table[{x, 
     z, \[ScriptCapitalB]BarMagnet[{x, 0., z}, {1.5, .5, 
        5.5}] [[3]]}, {x, 0, 10, .1}, {z, 0, 10, .1}], 1]];
```

Second, we compute field lines with

```
X1 = ParametricNDSolveValue[{z'[t] == Bz[x[t], z[t]], 
   x'[t] == Bx[x[t], z[t]], x[0] == x0, z[0] == z0}, 
  x, {t, 0, 1000}, {x0, z0}]; 
Z1 = 
     ParametricNDSolveValue[{x'[t] == Bx[x[t], z[t]], 
       z'[t] == Bz[x[t], z[t]], x[0] == x0, z[0] == z0}, 
      z, {t, 0, 1000}, {x0, z0}];
```

Finally we plot stream lines with `StreamPlot[]` and `ParametricPlot[]`, and show in one plot

```
sp = StreamPlot[{Bx[x, z], Bz[x, z]} ,   {x, 0, 10}, {z, 0, 10}, 
                              PlotRange -> All,
                                StreamPoints -> Fine, 
  AspectRatio -> Automatic, Frame -> None, 
  StreamColorFunction -> "Rainbow", StreamScale -> None, 
  VectorPoints -> Fine, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
  MaxRecursion -> 2];
ppxz = ParametricPlot[
   Table[{X1[x0, 0.01][t], Z1[x0, 0.01][t]}, {x0, .1, .5, .1}], {t, 0,
     1000}, PlotStyle -> Red];

Show[sp, ppxz]
```

[image: Figure 2]

Comment: Thanks, but what I want is continuous field lines. In your example most of the field lines suddenly break. That is what I want to avoid!

Comment: @DrSvanHay ah, I don't pay attention for your question. See update to my answer.

Comment: Hmm, not sure about that. With continous I mean closed loop. The field lines in a magnetic field are sourceless and I want to plot the closed loops the field lines must form.

Comment: @DrSvanHay What is this picture for? Is it to illustrate continuous $\vec {B}$ field?

Comment: I ve added text to the illustration to clarify. The image shows two field lines that are the way I want them and one field line that is broken.

Comment: @DrSvanHay Please, see update to my answer.